# How to set minimum width for timeline header in Anychart Gantt?

Tags: javascript, anychart

The header levels look fine when there are few rows. But if there are many rows and date range is long, the header levels are not readable. Please let me know how to set minimum width for the level so that it can be readable

(few rows)
[image: (few rows)]

(many rows)
[image: (many rows)]

Comment: Do you apply any custom settings for the timeline headers? With the default settings the chart adjusts the granularity on the fly to provide good readability and avoid overlapping.

Comment: Yes. I have set to display only day level timeline header.

Comment: You force the chart to show 1 day period. In this case, it will always show 1-day granularity despite the visible range width. You should avoid it or switch the period manually at some point.